# Customizing La Clojure indentation

Tags: clojure, customization

I must be dense this morning :-).

According the the JetBrains La Clojure page, the plugin indentation is customizable. I can't find the customization anywhere. I looked in "File->Settings" everywhere and even did a search for "clojure".

Where can I find this?

I am running IntelliJ 9.0.3 CE (Build 95.429) with La Clojure 0.2.267 on OS X 10.6.4.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open Preferences. Under 'Project Settings'/'Code Style'/'General' you will see, in the right dialog area, a region named 'Tabs and Indents'. There you can find a tab page 'Clojure'. Select it and you can set the indentation. ;-)